# Count the occurrence of each letter in a file in Java

Tags: java, beginner

This program prompts the user to enter a file name and displays the occurrences of each letter in the file. 
Is there a simpler and more efficient way to do this? Please, help me figure this out. Thanks!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class OccurenceOfEachLetter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //declares variables
        String[] sentence = new String [23];
        int countA = 0;
        int countB = 0;
        int countC = 0;
        int countD = 0;
        int countE = 0;
        int countF = 0;
        int countG = 0;
        int countH = 0;
        int countI = 0;
        int countJ = 0;
        int countK = 0;
        int countL = 0;
        int countM = 0;
        int countN = 0;
        int countO = 0;
        int countP = 0;
        int countQ = 0;
        int countR = 0;
        int countS = 0;
        int countT = 0;
        int countU = 0;
        int countV = 0;
        int countW = 0;
        int countX = 0;
        int countY = 0;
        int countZ = 0;
        char words;
        //Get user input 
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a Filename: ");
        String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

        //Open file for reading
        Scanner inputStream = null;

        //catch exception
        try 
        {
            inputStream = new Scanner(new File(filename)); 
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.print("Error opening the " + filename);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //read form file and store in an array
        while(inputStream.hasNextLine()) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) 
            {
                sentence[i] = inputStream.nextLine();
                //counts the occurrence of each letter in each line of gettysburg.txt
                for(int j = 0; j < sentence[i].length() ;j++) 
                { 
                    words = sentence[i].charAt(j);
                    if(words == 'A' || words == 'a') 
                    {
                        countA++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'B' || words == 'b') 
                    {
                        countB++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'C' || words == 'c') 
                    {
                        countC++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'D' || words == 'd') 
                    {
                        countD++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'E' || words == 'e') 
                    {
                        countE++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'F' || words == 'f') 
                    {
                        countF++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'G' || words == 'g') 
                    {
                        countG++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'H' || words == 'h') 
                    {
                        countH++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'I' || words == 'i') 
                    {
                        countI++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'J' || words == 'j') 
                    {
                        countJ++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'K' || words == 'k') 
                    {
                        countK++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'L' || words == 'l') 
                    {
                        countL++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'M' || words == 'm') 
                    {
                        countM++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'N' || words == 'n') 
                    {
                        countN++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'O' || words == 'o') 
                    {
                        countO++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'P' || words == 'p') 
                    {
                        countP++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'Q' || words == 'q') 
                    {
                        countQ++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'R' || words == 'r') 
                    {
                        countR++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'S' || words == 's') 
                    {
                        countS++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'T' || words == 't') 
                    {
                        countT++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'U' || words == 'u') 
                    {
                        countU++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'V' || words == 'v') 
                    {
                        countV++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'W' || words == 'w') 
                    {
                        countW++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'X' || words == 'x') 
                    {
                        countX++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'Y' || words == 'y') 
                    {
                        countY++;

                    }
                    if(words == 'Z' || words == 'z') 
                    {
                        countZ++;

                    }
                }
            }
        }//end while

        //close file
        inputStream.close();

        //Displays results
        System.out.println("The file gettysburg.txt contains the following: ");
        for(char i = 65 ; i <= 90;) 
        {
            int[] count = {countA, countB, countC, countD, countE, countF, countG, countH, countI, countJ, countK, countL, countM, countN, countO, countP, countQ, countR, countS, countT, countU, countV, countW, countX, countY, countZ};
            for(int j = 0; j< count.length;) 
            {
                System.out.println("Number of " + i +"'s: " + count[j]);
                j++;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }//ends main
}//ends class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to CodeReview! Especially as a beginner programmer, it takes bravery to show your code to the internet, but you've taken the first step.

This code has a long way to go, but I think it'll be a good learning experience for you.

```
//declares variables
```

Keep in mind that this isn't 1989-era C, so you don't need to predeclare all of your variables at the top of methods. Declare them where they're actually used.

```
String[] sentence = new String [23];
```

What is the number 23? This is a so-called magic number. If it really needs to be in the program, it should be put in its own named constant. However, I suspect that this is the number of lines of input. First: you already have logic to quit once you find the end of the file. Also: why store every line? You only need to store the results of letter summation, not the raw input. So this array is not necessary.

```
inputStream = new Scanner(new File(filename));
```

Google "try-with-resources". This will make it so that your program will close the file even if something goes wrong in the middle.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++)
```

This loop can go away entirely. The `while` above it already iterates through the lines of the file.

```
int countA = 0;
```

You should not have each of these as individual values. You arrived at the right idea later on with the `count` array. All of those individual letter count variables should go away and you should operate on the array directly.

Answer (score 2):

I focus on the operation of storing occurrences of single letters of a sentence in an array of ints and after print the number of occurrences for every single letter, I'm assuming that we are using the english alphabet:

```
int[] occurrences = new int[26];
```

Now start to examine a sentence and convert it to a char array:

```
String sentence = "Gettysburg, PA";
char[] arr = sentence.toCharArray();
final char initial = 'a';
```

You want to store only letters as case insensitive so for example occurrences of chars `A` and `a` will be stored in the same position of the occurrences array, you can do in this way:

```
for (char ch : arr) {
    if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
        char ch_lower = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
            ++occurrences[ch_lower - initial];
    }
}
```

You can refer to [Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) documentation for further details about methods I used in the loop. Now you can print all the occurrences in the array:

```
String format = "Number of %c: %d";
for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
    System.out.println(String.format(format, initial + i, occurrences[i]));
}
```

I used the method [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) for improve readibility of print code.
Below the code you can test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] occurrences = new int[26];


    final char initial = 'a';   
    String sentence = "Gettysburg, PA";
    char[] arr = sentence.toCharArray();
    for (char ch : arr) {
        if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
            char ch_lower = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
            ++occurrences[ch_lower - initial];
        }
    }
    String format = "Number of %c: %d";
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
        System.out.println(String.format(format, initial + i, occurrences[i]));
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not equivalent. You need to open a file.

Comment: @Reinderien Hello, I wrote at the start of  my answer that my focus is about storing occurrences of single letters of a sentence in an array of ints and after print them.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the next piece of code may be overwhelming for a Java beginner, due to the fact that it uses advanced features of the language such as streams, lambdas, and try-with-resource clauses. However, just for showing a different approach using functional programming, your program could be rewritten as follows:

```java
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Enter a Filename: ");
            Path file = Paths.get(scanner.next());
            try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(file)) {
                System.out.println("The file "+file+" contains the following: ");
                lines
                    .flatMapToInt(String::chars)
                    .filter(Character::isAlphabetic)
                    .map(Character::toLowerCase)
                    .mapToObj(c->(char)c)
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()))
                    .forEach((letter,count)->System.out.println("Number of "+letter+"'s: "+count));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error opening the file "+file);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
   }
```